# Find Aggregated Data Between Two Dates in Two Tables Where One is Updated Weekly and Other is Updated Hourly

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data in two different tables, one is updated every week or once in the middle of the week if needed, and the other table is updated every hour or so because it has more data. The first table, can be seen as

```
agent_id | rank | ranking_date
---------------------------
     1   |  1   | 2022-03-21
     2   |  2   | 2022-03-21
     1   |  4   | 2022-03-14
     2   |  3   | 2022-03-14
     1   |  2   | 2022-03-10
```

And the second table contains detailed information on sales.

```
agent_id | call_id | talk_time | product_sold | amount | call_date
------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     |    1    |    13     |      1       |   53   |2022-03-10
   1     |    2    |    24     |      2       |    2   |2022-03-10
   2     |    3    |    43     |      4       |   11   |2022-03-10
   1     |    4    |    31     |      -       |    0   |2022-03-10
   2     |    5    |    12     |      -       |    0   |2022-03-10
   1     |    6    |    11     |      -       |    0   |2022-03-11
   1     |    7    |    35     |      2       |   79   |2022-03-11
   2     |    8    |    76     |      -       |    0   |2022-03-11
   1     |    9    |    42     |      1       |   23   |2022-03-11
   2     |   10    |    69     |      -       |    0   |2022-03-11
```

How can I merge the two tables to get their aggregated information? Remember the ranks change at the beginning of every week, and the sales happen every day. But the rankings can also be changed in the middle of the week if needed. So what I am trying to get is created an aggregated table for understanding the sales by each agent. Something like this

```
agent_id | rank | ranking_date | total_calls_handled | total_talktime | total_amount
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     |  1   | 2022-03-21   |        100          |      875       |     3000 (this is 3/21 - today)
   2     |  2   | 2022-03-21   |        120          |      576       |     3689 (this is 3/21 - today)
   1     |  4   | 2022-03-14   |        210          |      246       |     1846 (this is 3/14 - 3/21)
   2     |  3   | 2022-03-14   |        169          |      693       |     8562 (this is 3/14 - 3/21)
   1     |  2   | 2022-03-10   |        201          |      559       |     1749 (this is 3/7 - 3/10)
```

So the data is aggregated for each agent from 7-10, 10 - 14, then 14-21. Also, if say, the latest ranking date is 2022-03-21, and today is 2022-03-23, the query returns aggregation until today.

[Edit]: added table and data details
Table and data details:
Rankings table:

- agent_id: unique_id of the agent
- rank: rank of an agent assigned updated every Monday or if needed
- ranking_date: date when agent's ranking was last updated (Automatically every Monday or if needed)

Sales Table:

- agent_id: unique_id of the agent
- call_id: unique_id for a call
- talk_time: duration of the call
- product_sold: unique_id of the product sold (- if agent was unsuccessful to sell)
- amount: commission earned by the agent (therefore same product_id has different amount) (0 if agent was unsuccessful to sell)
- call_date: date when which call was made

[Edit 2]: Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/021a76/2/0).

Comment: Do you want to join the 2 tables on week (date)= week (date) & agent=agent and group by week(date) and agent)?

Comment: Please give table definition and data of you want more help

Comment: Yes join on week(date)=week(date) & agent=agent and group by week(date) and agent, starting Mondays. But if ranking was updated on say, Thursday, then Monday to Thursday and then again Thursday to Monday. Also, I have edited to add more details on what each column contains in each table.

Comment: Edit2: added link for sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here we join where ranking_date and call_date are in the same week. If you make calls sunday you will need to check whether it falls in the same week as you want.
The syntax in the query is for SQL server, as the SQL Fiddle given. You will need to modify the line of the join to

```
on date_part(w,r.ranking_date) = date_part(w,s.call_date)
```

which should be compatible with Google Redshift.

> ```
> select 
>   r.agent_id,
>   r.rank,
>   r.ranking_date,
>   count(s.call_id) TotalCalls,
>   sum(s.talk_time) TotalTime,
>   sum(s.amount) TotalAmount
> from rankings r
> left join sales s
> on datename(ww,r.ranking_date)= datename(ww,s.call_date)
> group by
>   r.agent_id,
>   r.rank,
>   r.ranking_date
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> agent_id | rank | ranking_date | TotalCalls | TotalTime | TotalAmount
> -------: | ---: | :----------- | ---------: | --------: | ----------:
>        1 |    1 | 2022-03-21   |          0 |      null |        null
>        1 |    2 | 2022-03-10   |         10 |       356 |         168
>        1 |    4 | 2022-03-14   |          0 |      null |        null
>        2 |    2 | 2022-03-21   |          0 |      null |        null
>        2 |    3 | 2022-03-14   |          0 |      null |        null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0196351099f696cc82d45a7f92c71e94)*

Comment: This won't work because like I said, although rankings are updated every week, it can be updated in the middle of the week, and therefore, if I join on week of the year and agent_id, there will not be a proper match. Perhaps if the rows in ranking table are replicated to generate same ranks until next date, then there would be ranking for every day of the year, and then merge on sales, to get aggregations. Also, I am using aws redshift. Selected MS SQL on fiddle because there wasn't aws redshift. Also, if merging on week of the year, it will fail if year changes

Comment: The idea of joining on week is that if the ranking date changes from Monday to Thursday, for example, it's still the same week. Yes there will be a problem once a year. Either you live with it (depending on the industry you might even be shut?) or we code for it.